# Specify which jar wins when conflicts in Maven Shade

Tags: maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to use the Maven Shade plugin to build an `uber-jar`. Two of my dependencies include classes with the same name, in the same package, which have different implementations. I know this is a bad idea, but I do not have control over those depedencies. I know that, if a class shows up in `A.jar` and in `B.jar`, then the version in `B.jar` is the one I want to use.

Is there a way to tell the Shade plugin which `jar` to use when there is a conflict?

I am currently manually building a list of the conflicts and using a filter to exclude them from `A.jar`. That should work, but an having Shade pick the correct one would be simpler and future proof.

The dependency is a transitive dependency, so it is not obvious that "list `B` before `A` in your POM" will work.  It might work if you list the dependencies explicitly, although I was unable to find any information about how it picks when there are duplicates.

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to write your own [transformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html)?